# Hyper Ledge Fabric : Endorsement policy not reflecting

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I have a three ORG setup and I have installed chain code on all three ORG peers with endorsement policy `OutOf(2, 'Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member', 'Org3MSP.member')`. Chain code installed on ORG2 is different with ORG1 and ORG3 as it produces response with different value then ORG1 and ORG3 chaincode . One of the attribute of response is hard coded in contract of ORG2.

Now with above policy and setup, i would assume that with ORG2 response is different then ORG1 and ORG3 response ,and ORG1 and ORG3 response are identical , still the transaction should be successful as 2 out of three are satisfied . But I am getting below error when I am submitting the transaction. It works fine when I install correct chaincode on ORG2 . Can anyone please help in pointing out what am I doing wrong. For chaincode and application i am using java sdk. Please let me know if you need any specific details.

> Error : The proposal responses have 2 inconsistent groups with 0 that
> are invalid. Expected all to be consistent and none to be invalid

Comment: Can you give me information about the chaincode? Are the chaincodes between real organizations all the same?

Comment: @myeongkilkim Thanks for your response . I found my mistake . I had set discovery false in my client application code . Due to which it was failing . Once i turned it on it worked fine as expected . Thanks again for reaching out to help. Answering your question. Consortium is of three organisation, 2 have exactly same chaincode and one have a chaincode which produces different result although contract interface is same. This I did intentionally to test if endorsement policy works as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake . I had set discovery false in my client application code . Due to which it was failing . Once i turned it on (set as true) it worked fine as expected . You can use below discovery command to check the endorsement policies applicable on chaincode installed .

```
discover --configFile discovery/config.yaml endorsers --channel mychannel  --server peer0.org3.example.com:11051 --chaincode papercontract
```